# Replace newlines in multiline input with "\n"

Tags: bash, php

I've been trying to do some work with generating SQL commands with an interactive bash script and have a multiline string that I need to escape for use with MySQL.

Notes has already been defined as a multi-line string.

```
notes=$(echo "$notes" | php -r 'echo mysql_escape_string(fgets(STDIN));');
```

However, only one line is being returned. How can I get my multiline string properly escaped and returned?

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern substitution:

```
notes=${notes//$'\n'/\\n}
```